# How do I remove the default border glow of a JavaFX button (when selected)?

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to remove the border glow (please see screenshot below) that appears by default when a JavaFX button is selected:

[image: The blue border is the default styling by JavaFX for when the the button is selected]

I also want to do this using CSS, and not declaratively from within the main JavaFX script. However, I am having trouble figuring out what CSS property I need to use (er, set to 0?) in order to remove that border.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

**Setting `-fx-focus-color`**

Ensure that you review all updates to the answer to help you choose the appropriate solution to your problem.

To remove the focus ring display from any control from within code:

```
control.setStyle("-fx-focus-color: transparent;");
```

To remove the focus ring for all controls, apply a stylesheet:

```
.root { -fx-focus-color: transparent; }
```

To only remove the ring for all buttons, use:

```
.button { -fx-focus-color: transparent; }
```

I find the `-fx-focus-color` attribute setting more straight-forward than relying on some weird combination of insets to remove the focus ring.

In addition, you can use the same setting to change the focus ring to a different color, such as `-fx-focus-color: firebrick`.

**Update Jan 20, 2015 : addition of `-fx-faint-focus-color`**

JavaFX 8 shipped with a new default user agent stylesheet ([modena](http://fxexperience.com/2013/01/modena-new-theme-for-javafx-8/)).  This new user agent stylesheet shipped with an additional setting for focus highlights: `-fx-faint-focus-color`.  For Java 8 applications, it is necessary to set both `-fx-focus-color` and `-fx-faint-focus-color` to transparent to remove all traces of the focus ring.  See good4m's answer to this question.

**Update Dec 10, 2015: keeping exact rendering for specific controls**

If you only set the focus colors to transparent as previously recommended in this answer, for some controls you may see some subtle differentiation between when a control is focused and when it is not.  For many applications this will not be an issue and setting the focus colors to transparent will be sufficient.

For more information and alternate solutions, review James_D's answer to [Remove blue frame from JavaFX input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23374244/remove-blue-frame-from-javafx-input-field) and Jens Deter's blog post about [How to get rid of focus highlighting in JavaFX](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/11/how-to-get-rid-of-focus-highlighting-in-javafx.html).  Be aware that the link to Jens Deter's blog unfortunately has some annoying pop-ups.

**Update Sept, 2023: keeping exact rendering for a wider range of controls**

To get the focused things to look *exactly* like unfocused things, define `:focused` styles with the same CSS rules when focused as when unfocused.  The CSS rules below demonstrate this approach for many common JavaFX controls.

Unlike just setting the `-fx-focus-color` and `-fx-faint-focus-color` values, these rules will ensure that all aspects of the focused item size, padding, background etc, remain the same whether the item is focused or not.

JavaFX generally implements focus indication by additional layered backgrounds.  To render the focus ring, the number and size of the control backgrounds are adjusted, leading to a slightly different rendering of the control if you just set the focus ring to transparent.  If instead you override the focus CSS rules so they don't adjust the backgrounds of the control in any way, the control will look the same when the control is focused as it did when it was not focused.

The style sheet below was created by redefining many of the `:focused` CSS rules in the `modena.css` stylesheet found in the javafx controls jar file.  The new rules are set so that the `:focused` rules are defined to be the same values as unfocused rules.

I generated the style sheet by copy-and-paste and changing items manually.  It is not fully tested, so there may be some errors (if so, feel free to edit the post and correct them).

The list is currently deliberately incomplete, but if you have a rule that is important for a particular JavaFX control not demonstrated here and you are sure your rule is correct and optimal, please edit the example style sheet to add the additional rules.  In particular, it leaves out removing styling focus handling for tables as that can be quite complex.  That could perhaps handled through a separate question and answer.

The JavaFX version used for the template was 20.0.2.  Future JavaFX versions may have different rules, to which the rules below would need to adapt.

I do not think removing the focus ring from things is a good idea in most cases, so I encourage you not to do this.  In particular, it would not be recommended to remove focus rules for all controls in the entire application as that could be confusing to the user.  But in cases where it is your desired functionality, you may wish to selectively apply excerpts from the CSS rules below on the controls you wish to adjust.

```
/* ====   BUTTON LIKE THINGS   ============================================== */
.button:focused,
.toggle-button:focused,
.radio-button:focused > .radio,
.check-box:focused > .box,
.menu-button:focused,
.choice-box:focused,
.color-picker.split-button:focused > .color-picker-label,
.combo-box-base:focused,
.slider:focused .thumb {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-shadow-highlight-color, -fx-outer-border, -fx-inner-border, -fx-body-color;
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0, 0, 1, 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 3px, 3px, 2px, 1px;
}

/* ====   BOX LIKE THINGS   ================================================= */
.scroll-pane:focused,
.split-pane:focused,
.list-view:focused,
.tree-view:focused,
.table-view:focused,
.tree-table-view:focused,
.html-editor:contains-focus {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-box-border, -fx-control-inner-background;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1;
    -fx-padding: 1;
}

.scroll-pane:focused,
.split-pane:focused {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-box-border, -fx-background;
}

/* ====   PILL BUTTONS   ==================================================== */

.button.left-pill:focused,
.toggle-button.left-pill:focused {
    -fx-background-radius: 0 3 3 0, 0 3 3 0, 0 2 2 0, 0 1 1 0;
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0, 0, 1 1 1 0, 2 2 2 1 ;
}
.button.center-pill:focused,
.toggle-button.center-pill:focused {
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0, 0 0 0 0, 1 1 1 0, 2 2 2 1 ;
}
.button.right-pill:focused,
.toggle-button.right-pill:focused {
    -fx-background-radius: 0 3 3 0, 0 3 3 0, 0 2 2 0, 0 1 1 0;
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0, 0, 1 1 1 0, 2 2 2 1 ;
}

/* ====   SELECTED TOGGLE   ================================================= */

.toggle-button:selected:focused {
    -fx-background-color:
            -fx-shadow-highlight-color,
            linear-gradient(to bottom, derive(-fx-outer-border, -20%), -fx-outer-border),
            linear-gradient(to bottom,
            derive(-fx-color, -22%) 0%,
            derive(-fx-color, -13%) 20%,
            derive(-fx-color, -11%) 50%);
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0, 0, 1;
}

/* ====   RADIO             ================================================= */

.radio-button:focused > .radio  {
    -fx-background-radius: 1.0em; /* large value to make sure this remains circular */
    -fx-padding: 0.333333em; /* 4 -- padding from outside edge to the inner black dot */
}

/* ====   HYPERLINK         ================================================= */

.hyperlink:focused {
    -fx-border-color: transparent;
    -fx-border-width: 0px;
}

/* ====   SPLIT MENU BUTTON ================================================= */

.split-menu-button:focused {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-shadow-highlight-color, -fx-outer-border;
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0, 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 3, 3;
}

.split-menu-button:focused > .label {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-inner-border, -fx-body-color;
    -fx-background-insets: 1 0 1 1, 2 1 2 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 2 0 0 2, 1 0 0 1;
}
.split-menu-button:focused > .arrow-button {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-inner-border, -fx-body-color;
    -fx-background-insets: 1, 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 0 2 2 0, 0 1 1 0;
}

/* ====   TOOLBAR           ================================================= */

.tool-bar-overflow-button:focused > .arrow {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-mark-highlight-color, -fx-mark-color;
    -fx-background-insets: 1 0 -1 0, 0;
}

/* ====   SCROLLBAR         ================================================= */

.scroll-bar:horizontal:focused {
    -fx-background-color: derive(-fx-box-border,30%), linear-gradient(to bottom, derive(-fx-base,-3%), derive(-fx-base,5%) 50%, derive(-fx-base,-3%));
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1 0 1 0;
}
.scroll-bar:vertical:focused {
    -fx-background-color: derive(-fx-box-border,30%), linear-gradient(to right, derive(-fx-base,-3%), derive(-fx-base,5%) 50%, derive(-fx-base,-3%));
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 1 0 1;
}

/* ====   TEXT INPUT        ================================================= */

.text-input:focused {
    -fx-highlight-fill: derive(-fx-control-inner-background,-20%);
    -fx-highlight-text-fill: -fx-text-inner-color;
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, derive(-fx-text-box-border, -10%), -fx-text-box-border),
    linear-gradient(from 0px 0px to 0px 5px, derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -9%), -fx-control-inner-background);
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1;
    -fx-background-radius: 3, 2;
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: transparent;
}

/* ====   TEXT AREA        ================================================= */

.text-area:focused .content {
    -fx-background-color:
            linear-gradient(from 0px 0px to 0px 4px, derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -8%), -fx-control-inner-background);
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 2;
}

/* ====   MENU             ================================================= */

.menu:focused > .right-container > .arrow {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-mark-color;
}

/* ====   MENU ITEM        ================================================= */

.menu-item:focused {
    -fx-background: -fx-selection-bar;
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-text-fill:  -fx-text-background-color;
}
.menu-item:focused > .label {
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-text-base-color;
}
```

Comment: How I can remove radius too?

Comment: @Unknown, the radius isn't related to the focus ring.  See [styling a button with css](http://fxexperience.com/2011/12/styling-fx-buttons-with-css/).  If the link doesn't answer your question, ask a new question.

Comment: @jewelsea no body is answering my already asked question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38545939/customize-javafx-menubar-to-remove-margin That's why I tried to ask in comments. ( Not the same question but have a problem )

Answer (score 70):

```
-fx-focus-color: transparent;
-fx-faint-focus-color: transparent;
```

Answer (score 21):

If you want to remove this focus ring in JavaFX 8, rewrite the :focus selector with the .button selector style from modena.css.

```
.button:focused {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-outer-border, -fx-inner-border, -fx-body-color; 
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1, 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 5, 4, 3;
}
```

Comment: This needs to be higher up. All other solutions here won't work for JavaFX 8.

Comment: This one seems to come the closest, but the corners on a focused button have a different radius.

Comment: Ya for me just the `-fx-background-color` line was needed.

Answer (score 20):

There is several way to do this. You can try any of this.

```
button.setStyle("-fx-focus-color: transparent;");
```

or

```
.button{
    -fx-focus-color: transparent;
}
```

or

```
.button:focused{
     -fx-focus-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

The answer from [Stelios Adamantidis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1303323/stelios-adamantidis) is correct, which is

```
.button:focused {
  -fx-background-insets: 0, 0, 1, 2;
}
```

**Here is my explanation:**
For example the definition

```
-fx-background-color: red, green, deepskyblue, blue;
```

seems to define four layers of background colors, with red as the color for the backmost layer.

For example the definition

```
-fx-background-radius: 0, 1, 4, 10;
```

sets the radius for all corners for each color layer. Here, the red layer has all corners with the radius of 0, the green layer has all corners with the radius of 1 and so on.

For example the definition

```
-fx-background-insets: -10, 0, 3, 5;
```

sets the padding for the color layers. You can also set negative values then the color will be around the control.

The default values for a button seem to be something like this:

```
.button:focused {
  -fx-background-color: <blueGlowingColor>, <?>, <?>, linear-gradient(to bottom, <?>, <?>);
  -fx-background-insets: -1, 0, 1, 2;
}
```

Setting the first value of insets to 0 hides the glowing color behind the second color.

More about JavaFX CSS you can find here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html

Answer (score 10):

To completely disable this button selecting do:

```
button.setFocusTraversable(false);
```

It's much cleaner than editing in css.

Comment: Better answer for JavaFX 8+. May be adjusted in Scene Builder too.

Comment: yes, this should be the accepted answer currently :)

Comment: Doing this with ListView disable the ability to move the list with keyboard.