# Remove Focus Box Around TextField

Tags: javafx

Using JavaFX when I create a TextField and set

```
numberField.setFocusTraversable(false);
```

and then click on the field the blue box shows up around it.  I guess that makes sense
but there is no

```
setFocus(bool)
```

command.

I want to get rid of the box.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `setFocusTraversable(false)` disables the focus traversing (by TAB and SHIFT+TAB) for that node. Thus  it has nothing related with node's GUI style. To hide the focused blue color do:
Via code

```
numberField.setStyle("-fx-focus-color: transparent;");
```

or via css file

```
.text-field {
    -fx-focus-color: transparent;
}
```

or pseudo class in css file

```
.text-field:focused{
     -fx-focus-color: transparent;
}
```

`-fx-focus-color` is not a css property, it is a predefined color of caspian.css (JavaFX 2).

This answer is related to and referenced from: [How do I remove the default border glow of a JavaFX button (when selected)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092500/how-do-i-remove-the-default-border-glow-of-a-javafx-button-when-selected).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed help!  I am sure it will help others out.