# JavaFX: How to position a component/node?

Tags: javafx, positioning

In JavaFX, is there something similar to `setLayout();` or  `setBounds();`?

For example, I want to position a button to a position that I desire.

Answer (score 15):

Everything on JavaFX scene graph is a [Node](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html). Each node has a X-coordinate and a Y-coordinate. But there are different ways to `set/change position` of a child component. It depends on the layout manager used to show the component on the scene graph.

- There are layout managers, like `Group`, which do not compute child's default position and you can use [`layoutX`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#layoutXProperty) and [`layoutY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#layoutYProperty) directly on them
- There are other layout managers, like `Region`, which `automatically` compute child's default position using `layoutX` and inorder to adjust the locations of the components from their default positions you need to use [`translateX`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#translateXProperty--) and [`translateY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#translateYProperty--) values.

***From the docs :***

> If the node is managed and has a Region as its parent, then the layout region will set layoutX according to its own layout policy. If the node is unmanaged or parented by a Group, then the application may set layoutX directly to position it.

Answer (score 1):

You should read up on the [Node](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) class (the long text at the beginning), and then especially [relocate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#relocate-double-double-), [setLayoutX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setLayoutX-double-) (and Y) and [setTranslateX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setTranslateX-double-) (and Y).

Answer (score -2):

In addition to what others already mentioned, if you could place your button (or any node for that matter) inside a `StackPane`, then you could make use of the `StackPane`'s alignment property that takes `javafx.geometry.Pos` (the alignment of the child within the `StackPane`). For example in your case:

```xml
<StackPane>
    <Button translateY="-15" translateX="15"  StackPane.alignment="TOP_RIGHT"/>
</StackPane>
```

Comment: see my comment to your [duplicate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56591900/203657)