# JavaFX: Align Buttons inside ButtonBar (using SceneBuilder or fxml)

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, fxml, scenebuilder

I have a JavaFX [`ButtonBar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ButtonBar.html) with two Buttons (created via SceneBuilder).
I want one of the buttons to be left-aligned and the other right-aligned. (see screenshot)

[image]

From the docs I already know how I could achieve this inside the java-source-code:

```
ButtonBar.setButtonData(newButton, ButtonData.LEFT);
```

## BUT

I want to know how to achieve this WITHOUT having to write this inside my java-files but
 **how I can achieve this using just SceneBuilder or the corresponding fxml file**.

My .fxml file currently looks like this:

```
<ButtonBar>
  <buttons>
    <Button text="New" />
    <Button text="Save" />
  </buttons>
</ButtonBar>
```

* I'm on Windows

** [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24896498/how-to-right-allign-a-button-in-java-fx-toolbar/24905704#24905704) is not what I want, because he is using a ToolBar, but I want to know how to do this with a ButtonBar (and his approach does not work for the ButtonBar)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After some Trial and Error I found at least a way to do it directly via the .fxml-file:

You can assign the Button elements with `ButtonBar.buttonData` attributes and then assign a value to them.

```
<ButtonBar>
  <buttons>
    <Button text="New" ButtonBar.buttonData="LEFT" />
    <Button text="Save" ButtonBar.buttonData="RIGHT" />
  </buttons>
</ButtonBar>
```

The docs for the [ButtonBar.ButtonData enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ButtonBar.ButtonData.html) are pretty straighforward. So I found the solution to my problem with the "LEFT" and "RIGHT" enum values.

## STILL

If anyone knows/finds out how to do this directly in SceneBuilder, I would be grateful!

Comment: In SceneBuilder you can change the `ButtonOrder` property of the `ButtonBar`. If you put `U+` at the beginning instead of middle, all your unknown buttons will be left-aligned. But I haven't found a way to do this per-button; and my "left-aligned" buttons seem to end up centered... :(

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Via the Inspector, usually on the right side in NetBeans, you will find the tab "Layout".
Open it and scroll to the section "Transform".

The option "Translate X" is for adjusting the buttons in the buttonbar at the x-axis.

Answer (score 1):

There is the "**Transforms**" property in **Layout** tab of the button on the right side of Scene Builder. Change "**Translate X**". (The position of the button will change horizontally.)
"**Translate Y**" will change the button's position vertically.
You need to calculate the position first.

I just found it.

Comment: change to what? What the input should be?

Comment: positive or negative numbers.