# How to position a specific Tab on a TabPane to the right side while keeping the others on the left?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I'm using JavaFX w/ CSS to develop and application. Right now, I currently have a list of tabs within a TabPane, and it looks like so:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is keep the Play, News, & Profiles tab on the left, however I want the "Add User" on the right, as shown:

[image]

The only styles I have applied are to remove padding and change the colors of things. How would I be able to move the "Add User" tab to the right like shown in the mockup?

Comment: not supported - no easy way to tweak the internal layout (happens in package-scope classes inside TabPaneSkin), at least none that I could find in a quick check

Comment: Unfortunately, TabPane doesn't provide such functionality.  *An alternative workaround* - Make a custom Pane(or BorderPane), add a VBox on the top and add two children on it with *LEFT* and *RIGHT* alignment respectively. Add buttons(Play, News, Profiles, Add User) on those VBoxes based on your desired alignment. And setAction on those buttons and switch content-pane(should be shown in the center of your pane) regarding it. (and you can add animations to get the reflect as TabPane while switching panes). It may take a while to make it work - *but it will worth it* and customizable as well.

Comment: That's unfortunate to hear. It's sad that there's no native solution to this, because so far everything in JavaFX has been a breeze to implement compared to swing because of CSS haha. Thanks, I'll probably take the alternate route of creating my own TabPane-like thing

Answer (score -5):

i dont know about javaFX never used it.

but css:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li.right{
 float:right;
}

li {
  float: left;
}


li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

.active {
  background-color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#home" class="active">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li class="right"><a href="#whatever">right</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

perhaps you get more support if you put more details in your question dont expect everyone tried JAVAFX but some people may have knowledge to answer question with more details and effort from you.

Comment: Unfortunately JavaFX using their own, custom version of CSS and floating doesn't work. Thanks for the effort in this answer though! :)

Comment: oh ok, JavaFX CSS does not support CSS layout properties such as float, position, overflow, and width. However, the CSS padding and margins properties are supported on some JavaFX scene graph objects. All other aspects of layout are handled programmatically in JavaFX code. In addition, CSS support for HTML-specific elements such as Tables are not supported since there is no equivalent construct in JavaFX.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24896498/how-to-right-align-a-button-in-java-fx-toolbar

Comment: Thanks for that Stack overflow link. I'll check it out tomorrow, I posted this right before bed haha