# Remove Blue Box JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx-8

Whenever I open my JavaFX program, I there is a blue box around the first item in a `TableView`. Once the user clicks away, it's gone. Is there a way to remove it in a custom css file?

[image: Blue Box]

I've tried setting `-fx-focus-color` in `.root` and `.table-row-cell` (and much more that I can't remember) but nothing has worked.

Comment: Have you tried setting [`-fx-faint-focus-color` as in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15749763/1155209)?

Comment: You can debug this using [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) or the [SceneBuilder CSS Analyzer](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/scenebuilder/1/user_guide/stylesheet-support.htm).

Comment: hmm... you really want to remove the focus indicator? That's breaking user expectations. That said: since some versions (can't recall when it started) the initial focus is forced onto the first item - so you could try to clear it

Comment: @kleopatra I made a custom highlight so I don't want to see the default focus indicator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't change the color to `transparent` but I was able to hide it by using

```
.table-row-cell:focused{
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
}
```