# Remove the glowing border from focused tab with CSS

Tags: java, css, user-interface, javafx

I am trying to remove the blue glowing border, which apears when the pane is focused of a tab in a tabpane in my javaFX application. any idea on how to do this in css?

[image: blue border when focused]

This is my current css:

```
 .tab{
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-background-color:  derive(-fx-base, 0%);
    -fx-background-insets: 0.3; 
    -fx-focus-color: XXXXXX;
    }
.tab:hover{
    -fx-background-color:  derive(-fx-base, 20%);
}
.tab:selected{
    -fx-background-color:  derive(-fx-base, 60%);
}
```

but i dont know which value i should give focuse color to match the background `derive(-fx-base, 60%)` i can see a difference and if i set it to `-fx-background-color` i get an error

Comment: outline: none; should be the CSS rule for that, but I don't work with javaFX so I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for. sorry if it's not.

Comment: Related, but not identical, question: [How do I remove the default border glow of a JavaFX button (when selected)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092500/how-do-i-remove-the-default-border-glow-of-a-javafx-button-when-selected)

Comment: -fx-focus-color:  transparent doesnt work for me i can see a little difference between the tab and the bordercolor

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to set the border color to transparent.

```
.tab-pane:focused > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab:selected .focus-indicator {
    -fx-border-color: transparent;
}
```

You can also set the focus color and the faint focus color (used for the inset border) directly.

```
.tab-pane:focused > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab:selected .focus-indicator {
    -fx-focus-color: transparent;
    -fx-faint-focus-color: transparent;
}
```

I used the specific class here, but it also works with the tab class.

```
.tab {
    -fx-focus-color: transparent;
    -fx-faint-focus-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: I realize this is crazy old but I have not been able to find documentation on .focus-indicator. How did you determine this to be the part of the CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
 .tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab:selected 
{
 -fx-focus-color:  transparent;  //red;
}
```

Comment: works it colors the border red but i can't make it fit do  derive(-fx-base, 60%)

Comment: works with the transparent but i see the difference it should be the same color the tab is