# How to remove blue border from TableColumn in JavaFX during reordering

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-8, tablecolumn

I'm working with JavaFX and facing an issue with the TableView component. Whenever I reorder a column, a blue border appears around the column and there is blue box of the header. Can i change the color of it?

[image]

I've tried various CSS approaches to override this styling, such as setting -fx-border-color to transparent and adjusting the :focused, :hover, and :pressed pseudo-classes for .table-view .column-header and .table-cell, but nothing seems to work.

Do anyone have a solution?

I tried

```
.root {
    -fx-focus-color: transparent;
    -fx-faint-focus-color: transparent
}
```

and many other solutions I found but none of them works.

Comment: Related: [How do I remove the default border glow of a JavaFX button (when selected)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092500/how-do-i-remove-the-default-border-glow-of-a-javafx-button-when-selected).

Comment: Although the related question contains some hints on how to remove the focus ring for many controls, it is not an exact duplicate, as it states: "The list is currently deliberately incomplete, but if you have a rule that is important for a particular JavaFX control not demonstrated here and you are sure your rule is correct and optimal, please edit the example style sheet to add the additional rules. In particular, it leaves out removing styling focus handling for tables as that can be quite complex."

Comment: @jewelsea I know, some rules to change trivial styles in javafx are really complex in some cases. If you would by any chance find the solution, please anwser the question above. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: Yes, that is true.  However, in my opinion, table styling for interactive UIs such as JavaFX is not trivial. Providing an answer that disables default focus styling for JavaFX tables would also not be trivial (and I don't have time to do that now).  That is just my opinion though and my opinion could be proven wrong.